# Add text info to each row in Python dictWriter

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm using DictWriter in Python 3 to output an Object's state into a text file, like so:

```
def to_csv(self):
    with open('filename', 'w') as myfile:
        fieldnames = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
        wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        wr.writeheader()
        for idx, row in enumerate(self.tasks):
            wr.writerow(row)
```

I would however like to add an additional column into the output. Here's what I'm trying to get at:

```
wr.writerow(row + 'task number:'+idx)
```

Any pythonic way to do this? I guess I could prepare a string with each row, append the task number to that string & then pass that to the writerow (using a regular writer instead of DictWriter), but I'd like to not mess around with string & use the DictWriter directly if possible...

Comment: Why wouldn't `wr.writerow(row + {'task number': idx})` work? Just add it to the list of field names, and you're golden.

Comment: But I don't want to add a field to the dictionnary itself, if that's what you mean? Because simply concatenating them within writerow isn't accepted - there's no + operator defined... even if you concatenate a dict row to a dict row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, I would create a new dict and update it in each row. That's probably one of the clearest, most obvious approaches.

```
fieldnames = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'task number']
wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
wr.writeheader()
for idx, row in enumerate(self.tasks):
    seed = {'task number': idx}
    seed.update(row)
    wr.writerow(seed)
```

Comment: That works out - I don't have that much calls to write out that and I get to keep working with dictwriter which makes things simpler... thanks.